# Applications of differential equations that boil down to tridiagonal matrix when solved using implicit methods

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, applications, implicit-differentiation

I am looking for actual applications where differential equations are solved using implicit methods that boil down to solving a tridiagonal every time step. I found that there are heat equations and others that boil down to tridiagonals, but I couldn't find any real world applications and values used.

I also read the answer in [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107264/essay-about-the-art-and-applications-of-differential-equations), which mentioned looking at [Princeton companion to mathematics](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/8350.html) to find applications, but what I need the actual values used one of these applications when an experiment is done.

I need this to test the accuracy of my implementation to solve this. If there is a easier way to test the accuracy of a solver, I am open to those ideas as well.